# array inside hidden element javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I'm an absolute javascript noob and am using ASP.net, in my code behind aspx.cs file, I declared the body of the web document using html tags as seen below...

```
public void CreateForm(string passengerType, int passengerCount)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= passengerCount; i++)
        {
            Response.Write("<table id=NameBirthTable" + passengerType + i + ">");
            Response.Write("<tr>"); 
               ...
            Response.Write("<td colspan=2><input id=MiddleName" + passengerType +i                + "type=text /></td>");
                ...
        }
    }
```

And when I try to call on the ID of an element, which is in id="MiddleName[passengerType][i]"
I can't find it, I need to get the value of that textbox and pass that into another page, Somebody suggested to me that I use javascript and try to store these elements inside a hidden element and add that to an array declared in javascript, I didn't get a single thing he said, any alternative suggestions?

Comment: give common class name.then on click get the id of respective clicked element..save it in hidden field,then access via code behind..

Comment: @Daniel: Question: when you say "*I can't find it, I need to get the value of that textbox and pass that into another page*", are you trying to do this at client side (i.e. javascript) or server side (i.e. c#)?

Comment: Please check if you are getting space characters in your `passengerType` value? If so then it would not create proper id. If this is the case, then you can try replacing the space character (i.e. " ") with say undescore (i.e. "_") by doing `passengerType=passengerType.replace(' ', '_')`

Comment: @purnil, I was tring to do it at both client side(using javascript) and server side,

Comment: Also, I make sure that the values passed onto passengerType do not involve spaces
in fact, they should only be,
"Adult", "Child","Infant"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
Response.Write("<td colspan=2><input id='MiddleName" + passengerType + i + "' type=text /></td>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you view source on your page you will probably see:

```
<td colspan=2><input id=MiddleNameXYZ1>
<td colspan=2><input id=MiddleNameXYZ2>
<td colspan=2><input id=MiddleNameXYZ3>
```

In other words, your coding is not formatting to what you think it should be.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do, does that mean that I can't call the value of that element by simply using the javascript code

Comment: You are expecting the format to look like:  id="MiddleName[passengerType][i]" right?

Comment: Yes, thank you for correcting me, I didn't quite understand your answer before, I am trying that right now

Answer (score 0):

Check tho source of your generated documents to see what id is generated as the output of your code. Bear in mind that asp.net control are rendered with different ids then server side  `ID`. To get it in your javascript function you need to do something like that:

```
function getElement(){
    var myEl = document.getElementByID('<%=ControlID.ClientID%>')
}
```

where `ControlID` is serverside ID of you control.

In your particular case ControlID might not be avalaible however, therefore it might be neccesary to create a property in the page class which will contain the control you add - for instance:

```
class MyPage:Page{
    TextBox TextBoxName {get;set;}

    public void CreateForm(string passengerType, int passengerCount)
    {
        TextBoxName = new TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(TextBoxName);
    }

}
```

I am aware that this code might not match your current implemantation, but in general it should work this way.

Comment: the question uses normal html element id's and not asp.net controls. So that would not change when rendered. Also these are not controls but just string, so you cannot do `<%=ControlID.ClientID%>` for them.

Comment: Tried it, resulted in an invalid id, I'm starting to think that I need to start from scratch as I was made aware by a senior programmer that it is not a good practice, I'll just attempt to create server side controls instead of using html tags, Thanks to everyone who were helping me

Comment: @Purnil Soni Textbox was mentioned in the question, so I thought it might have been added later in the code, especially that he did not show any '<input type="text" ...' in his example. Another thing is that I clearly stated that it might not match his implementation, and it is only an idea of how matching the ids on the client-side might be accomplished

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
public void CreateForm(string passengerType, int passengerCount)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("<table id='NameBirthTable" + passengerType  + "'>");
    for (int i = 1; i <= passengerCount; i++)
    {
        sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
        sb.AppendLine("<td colspan='2'><input id='MiddleName" + passengerType + i + "' type='text' /></td>");
    }
    sb.AppendLine("</table>");
    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This is same as the question says, just different way of achieving. How does this help towards the answer/solution?

Comment: @PurnilSoni it is not only introduce string builder, check I have move Table tag before the loop and added end table tag after the loop. and also added `''` for all the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

**On server-side** you can create a list of all created ids, and output them as value to an hidden field.

```
public void CreateForm(string passengerType, int passengerCount)
{
    /* List to hold id values */
    List<string> ids = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= passengerCount; i++)
    {
        Response.Write("<table id=NameBirthTable" + passengerType + i + ">");
        Response.Write("<tr>"); 
        //   ...
        Response.Write("<td colspan=2><input id=MiddleName" + passengerType +i+ "type=text /></td>");
        //    ...

        /* Add newly created input id to list */
        ids.Add("MiddleName" + passengerType +i);
    }

    /* Output the ids collection to hidden field value */
    Response.Write("<input type='hidden' id='hiddenElement' value='" + string.Join(",", ids.ToArray()) + "'></input>");
}
```

**On client side** javascript you can get all these ids from the hidden element, loop through them and get all created input elements

```
/* Get all ids from hidden element */
var ids = document.getElementById('hiddenElement').value.split(',');
/* Loop through all ids */
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var element = document.getElementById(ids[0]);
    // do something
}
```